# Is it possible to create indexes on virtual tables in SAP HANA?

Tags: hadoop, hana

We would like to load data from Hadoop into HANA using SDA and create virtual tables. Is it possible to create indexes on top of these tables?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. Indexes are part of the data storage structure and virtual tables are not "stored" in SAP HANA. Think of them rather as VIEWS instead.